# HttpResponse won't display `post` information when submitting a form

Tags: python, django, forms, post

I'm working my way through Django and I'm creating an app that will allow users to use an ID number to sign-in to a system. So I have two views, one for users to log-in, and the other to sign-up. The former view works just fine, I can get it to display the information the user has submitted. However I can't get the second view to display the `POST` data to the user:

```
from .forms import NameForm, IdForm
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def sign_in(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        #here will construct the form with the POST data
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        #the next part is to check that the information submitted is valid
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save()
            post.save()
            return HttpResponse(post)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Form is invalid")
    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'checkin/base.html', {'form': form})



def sign_up(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = IdForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save()
            post.save()
            return HttpResponse(post)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Form is invalid')
    else:
        form = IdForm()
    return render(request, 'checkin/base.html', {'form': form})
```

Basically I want to make the response to be "thank you, your ID number is: `post`".

Here is the class for my model:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

# Create your models here.

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField("What is your ID?", max_length=200)

    id_text = models.CharField("Enter a new identification          
    number",max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

And here are the form classes for both views:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Question

#put the form here

class NameForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['question_text']

class IdForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['id_text']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not generally acceptable to display the POST data as the respnose to the user. That's not HTML, merely a dictionary which the average user will not understand. The standard way of using forms in Django (and indeed almost any web framework) is to display the form validation errors to the user so that he may rectify it.

The right way

```
def sign_up(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = IdForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save()
            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/succes_url')
    else:
        form = IdForm()
    return render(request, 'checkin/base.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Okay thanks for the tip, but how would I show the user their input after it has been validated? i.e "Thank you for signing up your Id is: "

Comment: Would it make sense for me to maybe create a separate variable that's equal to the `POST` data and display that instead?

Comment: Well the user already knows what he entered so there is no need to tell him that! But if you think tis' important, put it into the sessions and pop it in the next page. Or better use django messages

Comment: Alright thanks a lot I'll look into Django messages. But what do you mean by "put it into the sessions"?

Comment: Or is that what `httpresponse` refers to?

Comment: sorry for late reply. I was speaking of this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in line **return HttpResponse(post)**,You are passing a whole form into HttpResponse,but as you mentioned,you just need **id_text** field of the **IdForm**.
So the updated code should be :

```
def sign_up(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = IdForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save()
            post.save()
            id = post.id_text
            return HttpResponse('thank you, your ID number is: '+id)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Form is invalid')
    else:
        form = IdForm()
    return render(request, 'checkin/base.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but why does posting the whole form in `httpresponse` work for my other view?